# How load data after all computed data from vuex store was loaded?

Tags: vuejs2

Working with Laravel 5.7 / Vuejs 2.6 / Vuex 3.1 app I use "vue-select": "^2.6.4" and when I open form with existing data I need 
to fill my select component with variable

```
selection_status = {key: ‘key’, label: ‘label’}



<v-select
      v-model="selection_status"
      data-vv-name="userRow.status"
      :options="customerStatusValueArray"
      v-validate="'required'"
      id="status"
      name="status"
      class="form-control editable_field"
      placeholder="Select option"
></v-select>


        data() {
            return {
                ...
                selection_status: null,


        mounted() {
            this.loadCustomer();
        }, // mounted() {


        loadCustomer() {
            axios.get(window.API_VERSION_LINK + 'personal/customers/' + this.user_id).then((response) => {
               this.userRow = response.data.user;

               this.customerStatusValueArray.map((nextCustomerStatusValue, index) => {
                   if (nextCustomerStatusValue.key == this.userRow.status) {
                       this.selection_status = {key: this.userRow.status, label: nextCustomerStatusValue.label};
                  }
               });
        ...

    computed: {
        customerStatusValueArray() {
            return this.$store.getters.customerStatusValueArray;
        },
```

I get customerStatusValueArray array from vuex store and I found that it is filled AFTER method loadCustomer from mounted is loaded, 
so this.selection_status is null.

Is there is a way to run

```
    this.loadCustomer();
```

after all computed data from vuex store is loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should use a loading state,
also consider using created() to call this.loadCustomer()
because mounted() its called after the component has been rendered.

```
<v-select v-if="loaded' />
<my-loader v-else/>

data() {
  loaded: false,
}

loadCustomer() {
  axios.get('url').then((response) => {
   this.loaded = true;
  });
}
```

**update:**
You can observe when your computed changes,
once customerStatusValueArray isn't empty you can call this.loadCustomer()

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    customerStatusValueArray: (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal.length > 0)
        this.loadCustomer()
    }
  }
  computed: {
    customerStatusValueArray() {
      return this.$store.getters.customerStatusValueArray;
    },
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: looks like with that v-select component would be rendered after page is loaded?

Comment: @PetroGromovo v-select will be rendered only when you set 'this.loaded = true' alternatively you can initialize selection_status: [], and add some message that its loading, this way you shouldn't get any error.

Comment: That is interesting, but seems not enough as computed value customerStatusValueArray  from vuex store must be inited/filled in loadCustomer method, but looks like it is empty...

Comment: @PetroGromovo You could [watch](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) customerStatusValueArray , i'm gonna update my answer